# Laravel error 405 (Method Not Allowed) on form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, modal-dialog

I have a modal with an empty `action=""` which I am updating with javascript like this

```
document.edit_matrix.action = '/matrix/' + id;
```

When I open the modal the changed action is there:

```
<form id="edit_matrix" name="edit_matrix" method="post" action="/matrix/3">
```

And then I click on submit and it tries to post on this current page....
It's simply an awful feeling :disappointed:
What is wrong? What do I need to change to make this work?
It tries to post to this:

```
POST https://global.test.loc/matrixes 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

[image]

This is the DOM after attribute update

---

Update:

Now I tried to hardcode the action like this:

```
 <form id="edit_matrix" action="/matrix/2" name="edit_matrix" method="POST">
```

and when I click submit button, nothing happens.... it's just dead

OK, I fixed that one... the type of the button was just button and not submit, but it's still not working
Tries to submit to original page.... action attribute doesn't change.

---

Update:

It works now... the button was inside the form partial and I just removed it out of the form partial to create and edit view and now it works.

Comment: — Could you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am making the fiddle example now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/62euvjsh/1/
It's same like this

Comment: but on fiddle it works. I don' get this

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I get this error `POST https://global.test.loc/matrixes 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Comment: Damn. I think I know what happened.... I have the same form for edit and update and both as modals on this page.... and when I click submit it posts the wrong form.
I need to investigate this further more.

Comment: It works now... the button was inside the form partial and I just removed it out of the form partial to create and edit view and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

use `setAttribute("action", "/newValue")`